# Can gpresult query the default user template on a standalone machine?

Tags: windows, group-policy

On a standalone machine I can query the local policy using gpresult and specifying the desired user account like so:

```
gpresult /USER username /h C:\report.html
```

How could I do the same thing, but for the default user template (i.e. the profile copied when creating a new user on the machine)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  `gpresult` needs a valid user context that actually exists to query.  You can't tell it to query ~"whatever a default user would be," least of all because that doesn't actually make sense.  There isn't a "null" or default user.  Both using the computer and applying policy (in Windows) always have a user context, even if that user isn't an actual user, but is `SYSTEM`, for example. So speaking of a "default" user, or a non-existent user is somewhat nonsensical.  (Really, what is the "default" user?  There are a number of users created by default on a Windows machine, and they're all very different.)

[And, in fact, gpresult will default to the logged on user running the query if the user argument is not provided](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

You can create a new user, accept the... "defaults" (to the extent that there are any)  and query against that user, which seems like the easiest way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks, although it proves I can't do what I was trying to do, it's a pretty comprehensive answer!